# RoboSpice throwing okhttp exceptions

Tags: java, android, retrofit, robospice

I use RoboSpice-Retrofit for calling my server REST api which has been working without problems until a few days ago when every single call now throws an exception, Example:

```
D/Retrofit: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Lcom/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient;Lcom/squareup/okhttp/Request;ZZZLcom/squareup/okhttp/Connection;Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/RouteSelector;Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/RetryableSink;Lcom/squareup/okhttp/Response;)V in class Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpEngine; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine' appears in /data/app/com.company.app.customerapp-1/base.apk)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.newHttpEngine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:362)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.initHttpEngine(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:312)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:377)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:497)
            at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.readResponse(UrlConnectionClient.java:73)
            at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:38)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:321)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
            at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
            at $Proxy0.getTest(Unknown Source)
            at com.adoperator.tidyapp.TestActivity$TestRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(TestActivity.java:67)
            at com.adoperator.tidyapp.TestActivity$TestRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(TestActivity.java:54)
            at com.octo.android.robospice.request.CachedSpiceRequest.loadDataFromNetwork(CachedSpiceRequest.java:48)
            at com.octo.android.robospice.request.DefaultRequestRunner.processRequest(DefaultRequestRunner.java:150)
            at com.octo.android.robospice.request.DefaultRequestRunner$1.run(DefaultRequestRunner.java:217)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
D/Retrofit: ---- END ERROR
```

## dependencies:

```
compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice:1.4.14'
compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-cache:1.4.14'
compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-retrofit:1.4.14'
```

I suspect based on the exception that there is something wrong with the compiler, but I just tested on another computer with a fresh install of Java and Android Studio on the same project but same problems still...

This error is driving me crazy...

Anyone knows anything that could be of help? Any help is highly appreciated.

## EDIT

> MainActivity.java:

```
SpiceManager spiceManager = new SpiceManager(TestAPIService.class);

protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    spiceManager.start(this);

    spiceManager.execute(new TestRequest(), new RequestListener<ResponseData>() {
        ...
    });
}
```

> TestAPIService.java:

```
public class TestAPIService extends RetrofitGsonSpiceService {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        addRetrofitInterface(TestAPI.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getServerUrl() {
        return "http://192.168.0.2";
    }
}
```

> TestAPI.java:

```
public interface TestAPI {
    @GET("/test")
    ResponseData getTest();
}
```

> TestRequest.java:

```
public class TestRequest extends RetrofitSpiceRequest<ResponseData, TestAPI> {

    public TestRequest() {
        super(ResponseData.class, TestAPI.class);
    }


    @Override
    public ResponseData loadDataFromNetwork() throws Exception {
        ResponseData response;

        try {
            response = getService().getTest();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: please, post your code, when you are configuring robospice.

Comment: I have added my code, thought, I haven't changed anything really, the errors just came from nowhere.

Comment: please, point me, where is line 67 and 54 in `TestActivity.java `

Comment: 67: `response = getService().getTest();` 54: `public class TestRequest extends RetrofitSpiceRequest<ResponseData, TestAPI> {`

Comment: sorry, but I don't know how to help you. But I see that you are use  `HttpURLConnection`, try to use robospice with okhttp

Comment: Now Im confused, I am using robospice with okhttp

Comment: sorry. You are right. I made a mistake. So, I still don't know how to help you. May be you need to create repository with this issue and report to robospice?

Comment: Yes I will create an issue on their github, thanks anyways.

Comment: Try adding the following dependency to your project:  `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.6.0'`

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/issues/365) may help you.

Comment: @heenenee Doesn't work

Comment: @pRaNaY I don't know what to do with that, also, that issue is not the same as mine.

Comment: Okay, try adding this one too then:  `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:1.6.0'`

Comment: @heenenee Nope, I dont think it has to do with any missing dependencies. I think it has to do with something much more complicated

Comment: It's not about missing dependencies, but I do think it's about incorrect transitive dependencies getting pulled into your build.  The `1.6.0` was a mistake; I got thrown off by [`robospice-okhttp`](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/blob/release/extensions/robospice-okhttp-parent/pom.xml#L26).  See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `NoSuchMethodError` is happening because `HttpURLConnectionImpl` is trying to invoke a constructor on `HttpEngine` that is not defined.  Now your project depends on:

```
com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-retrofit:1.4.14
```

Which [depends on](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/blob/robospice-parent-1.4.14/extensions/robospice-retrofit-parent/pom.xml#L40):

```
com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1
```

Which [depends on](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/parent-1.6.1/pom.xml#L104) both:

```
com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0
```

[and](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/parent-1.6.1/pom.xml#L109)

```
com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0
```

As of version `2.0.0`, `HttpURLConnectionImpl` is in the `okhttp-urlconnection` module and `HttpEngine` is in the `okhttp` module.
The `retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient` portion of your stack trace correctly matches [`retrofit:1.6.1`](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/parent-1.6.1/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/client/UrlConnectionClient.java#L73), but the `com.squareup.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl` portion doesn't match [`okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-2.0.0/okhttp-urlconnection/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/huc/HttpURLConnectionImpl.java#L349); it matches [`okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-2.4.0/okhttp-urlconnection/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/huc/HttpURLConnectionImpl.java#L362).  The constructor that the `NoSuchMethodError` is complaining about is indeed defined in [`okhttp:2.4.0`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/parent-2.4.0/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpEngine.java#L188), so that means there is a different `HttpEngine` on your classpath, most likely from a different version of `okhttp` that is getting pulled in by a transitive dependency.  You should be able to fix the problem by specifying the following dependencies:

```
compile('com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0') {
    force = true
}
compile('com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0') {
    force = true
}
```

If that doesn't work for whatever reason, the solution to your problem will still be to get your versions of `okhttp` and `okhttp-urlconnection` synced up and at a version that is compatible with your version of `retrofit`.  Declare dependencies similar to above, find the jars that contain `HttpURLConnectionImpl` and `HttpEngine`, [figure out how they're getting pulled in to your build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12289367/2646526), and use [exclusions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20073207/2646526) to get rid of problematic transitive dependencies.

Comment: Big thanks! Really well written answer and it worked and good researching!

Comment: Just so weird that I needed to add these manually because it did work just a week ago and I haven't changed my gradle file :S

Comment: Glad I could help.  Even if you haven't changed your build, this sort of thing can still happen if one of your dependencies changes their pom.xml, or if a dependency has a version range and a new applicable version is released.